# Small section with differente formating

Tags: spacing, itemize

I'm new to LateX and this actually is my first attempt with LateX.

I have the following code:

```
\begin{equation}
V^{\text{k+1}}_i=w V^k_i+c_1rand_1(pbest-s^k_i)+c_2.rand_2(gbest-s^k_i)\label{eq:4}
\end{equation}

Onde:

\begin{itemize}
    \item[\(V^{\text{k+1}}_i\)] é a velocidade da partícula \(i\) na iteração \(k\)
    \item[\(w\)] é uma função de ponderação
    \item[\(c_1 e c_2\)] são coeficientes de ponderação
    \item[\(rand\)] é um número aleatório de 0 a 1
    \item[\(s^k_i\)] é a posição da partícula \(i\) na iteração \(k\)
    \item[\(pbest\)] representa  as coordenadas do melhor resultado já encontrado pela partícula \(i\)
    \item[\(gbest\)] representa as coordenadas do melhor resultado encontrado por qualquer partícula
\end{itemize}
```

It's an equation and an `itemize` environment to describe the variables. But this environment is using the default paragraph spacing of the document. Is there any way to tell LateX to use single spacing in this environment only?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the spacing in the environment with `\setlenght\itemsep{0em}`to a smaller one. Note that you can change it also to negative values like `-2em` to get even smaller spacing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
V^{\text{k+1}}_i=w V^k_i+c_1rand_1(pbest-s^k_i)+c_2.rand_2(gbest-s^k_i)\label{eq:4}
\end{equation}

Onde:

\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \item[\(V^{\text{k+1}}_i\)] é a velocidade da partícula \(i\) na iteração \(k\)
    \item[\(w\)] é uma função de ponderação
    \item[\(c_1 e c_2\)] são coeficientes de ponderação
    \item[\(rand\)] é um número aleatório de 0 a 1
    \item[\(s^k_i\)] é a posição da partícula \(i\) na iteração \(k\)
    \item[\(pbest\)] representa  as coordenadas do melhor resultado já encontrado pela partícula \(i\)
    \item[\(gbest\)] representa as coordenadas do melhor resultado encontrado por qualquer partícula
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]